# The Argument type 'Context' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext' - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting an error on context, I also found a similar question here on stackoverflow but it didn't solve my problem. The answer to that question suggested to add `import 'package:path/path.dart';` but still I'm having the same error. Here is my code below:

```
import 'dart:js';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:chewie/chewie.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_rating_bar/flutter_rating_bar.dart';
import 'package:fluttershare/models/user.dart';
import 'package:fluttershare/pages/comments.dart';
import 'package:fluttershare/pages/home.dart';
import 'package:fluttershare/widgets/progress.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

class Post extends StatefulWidget {
  final String postId;
  final String ownerId;
  final String username;
  final String foodname;
  final String placename;
  final String cityname;
  final String statename;
  final String mediaUrl;
  final double rating;
  final dynamic likes;

  Post({
    this.postId,
    this.ownerId,
    this.username,
    this.foodname,
    this.placename,
    this.cityname,
    this.statename,
    this.mediaUrl,
    this.rating,
    this.likes,
  });

  factory Post.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    return Post(
      postId: doc['postId'],
      ownerId: doc['ownerId'],
      username: doc['username'],
      foodname: doc['foodname'],
      placename: doc['placename'],
      cityname: doc['cityname'],
      statename: doc['statename'],
      mediaUrl: doc['mediaUrl'],
      rating: doc['rating'],
      likes: doc['likes'],
    );
  }

  int getLikeCount(likes) {
    if (likes == null) {
      return 0;
    }
    int count = 0;
    likes.values.forEach((val) {
      if (val == true) {
        count += 1;
      }
    });
    return count;
  }

  @override
  _PostState createState() => _PostState(
        postId: this.postId,
        ownerId: this.ownerId,
        username: this.username,
        foodname: this.foodname,
        placename: this.placename,
        cityname: this.cityname,
        statename: this.statename,
        mediaUrl: this.mediaUrl,
        likes: this.likes,
        likeCount: getLikeCount(this.likes),
      );
}

class _PostState extends State<Post> {
  final String currentUserId = currentUser?.id;
  final String postId;
  final String ownerId;
  final String username;
  final String foodname;
  final String placename;
  final String cityname;
  final String statename;
  final String mediaUrl;
  String rating;
  int likeCount;
  Map likes;
  bool isLiked;

  _PostState({
    this.postId,
    this.ownerId,
    this.username,
    this.foodname,
    this.placename,
    this.cityname,
    this.statename,
    this.mediaUrl,
    this.rating,
    this.likes,
    this.likeCount,
  });

  buildPostHeader() {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: usersRef.document(ownerId).get(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return circularProgress();
        }
        User user = User.fromDocument(snapshot.data);
        return ListTile(
          leading: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: CachedNetworkImageProvider(user.photoUrl),
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
          ),
          title: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => print('showing profile'),
            child: Text(
              user.username,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          trailing: IconButton(
            onPressed: () => print('deleting post'),
            icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  VideoPlayerController _controller;
  Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(mediaUrl);
    _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller.initialize();
    _controller.setLooping(true);
    _controller.setVolume(1.0);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  //                                     Post Chewie Display...

  buildPostImage() {
    return FittedBox(
      fit: BoxFit.contain,
      child: mounted
          ? Chewie(
              controller: ChewieController(
                videoPlayerController: _controller,
                aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                autoPlay: false,
                autoInitialize: true,
                looping: true,
              ),
            )
          : Container(),
    );
  }

  handleLikePost() {
    bool _isLiked = likes[currentUserId] == true;

    if (_isLiked) {
      postsRef
          .document(ownerId)
          .collection('userPosts')
          .document(postId)
          .updateData({'likes.$currentUserId': false});
      setState(() {
        likeCount -= 1;
        isLiked = false;
        likes[currentUserId] = false;
      });
    } else if (!_isLiked) {
      postsRef
          .document(ownerId)
          .collection('userPosts')
          .document(postId)
          .updateData({'likes.$currentUserId': true});
      setState(() {
        likeCount += 1;
        isLiked = true;
        likes[currentUserId] = true;
      });
    }
  }

  buildPostFooter() {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0, left: 20.0)),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: handleLikePost,
              child: Icon(
                isLiked ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
                size: 28.0,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0)),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => showComments(
                context,
                postId: postId,
                ownerId: ownerId,
                mediaUrl: mediaUrl,
              ),
              child: Icon(
                Icons.supervised_user_circle,
                size: 28.0,
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 50.0)),
            Icon(Icons.location_on, color: Colors.blueAccent),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 2.0, top: 5.0, right: 10.0),
              child: Text("$cityname " + "$statename",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueAccent)),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
              child: Text(
                "$likeCount likes",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, top: 10.0, bottom: 5.0),
              child: Text(
                "$foodname ",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0)),
            Icon(
              Icons.restaurant,
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 2.0),
              child: Text(placename.toUpperCase(),
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    isLiked = (likes[currentUserId] == true);
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        buildPostHeader(),
        buildPostImage(),
        buildPostFooter(),
        Divider(),
        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0)),
      ],
    );
  }
}

showComments(BuildContext context,
    {String postId, String ownerId, String mediaUrl}) {
  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
    return Comments(
      postId: postId,
      postOwnerId: ownerId,
      postMediaUrl: mediaUrl,
    );
  }));
}
```

[The argument type 'Context' error... Image here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2z973.png)

Comment: I don't know how it's possible regarding your code, but your context variable is type of Context !? You could go to the definition this variable to understand why or where the type come from ?

Comment: @FPerroch The argument type 'JsObject' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable)

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know whether it's working or not ? @WaseemKhan

Comment: Is your issue solved? If it's working then kindly accept my answer. @WaseemKhan

Comment: @VinothVino Yes I did that, now there is a problem in compiling.

Compiler message:
lib/widgets/post.dart:1:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:js'
import 'dart:js';

Comment: It's just a warning, try commenting that import statement and check it. @WaseemKhan

Comment: @VinothVino Worked! Should I remove the dart:js then?

Comment: Yes, remove it you no need to have that one.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much for your time mate.

Comment: It's my pleasure, Happy Coding...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The argument type `Context` can't be assigned to the parameter type `BuildContext`.

So you need to pass the `BuildContext` instead of `Context` type. Try passing the build context to the `buildPostFooter` method from widget's build method.

```
buildPostFooter(BuildContext context){
  ...

  GestureDetector(
    onTap: () => showComments(
      context,
      postId: postId,
      ownerId: ownerId,
      mediaUrl: mediaUrl,
   ),
   child: Icon(
       Icons.supervised_user_circle,
       size: 28.0,
       color: Colors.blueAccent,
     ),
   ),

   ...
}
```

Then in your widget's build method. I hope this will solve your problem.

```
buildPostFooter(context),
```

Comment: getting same error of context at the place of progress listener I passed how to fix this in a flutter

Answer (score 2):

Set import as path

```
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;
```